# Can I install Magento OMS on Magento 2.2.8 (community)

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, order-management

We are a 42 branch + website Appliance store and are trying to make the move to Magento OMS. My question: Is it possible to do that with our current version of Magento or do we need Magento Enterprise to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to migrate

Technically speaking it is it's own version of magento

If you don't want to immediately deal with adobe you could try an agency. They will give you much more of an idea on cost.

Comment: Does migrate mean moving to Magento enterprise or just moving to third party extension offering Magento OMS? (like mageworx and such)

Comment: I meant moving to Magento OMS aka a streamline enterprise. But I'm in no doubt a more cost effective solution would be to use a third party extensions on your current platform. Ultimately it could be less work for yourselves too as you would keep your existing platform. Depends on what these third party plugins offer and whether that's enough for your business needs.